# Chrome not picking up form variables

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome

I have a form that feeds variables into a piece of javascript for building a graph. When running the page in chrome the submit button just reloads the page and the variable data from the form isn't gathered and fed into the javacript. Below is the snippet of code for the form and part of the javascript that picks up the variables and uses them in the URL.

This works perfectly in Firefox without a single error in sight. Chrome just refuses to pick up the input from the form. Unfortunately the console hasn't picked up any errors either. I've tried using POST, but this doesn't resolve the issue, GET works anyhow when I run the PHP page with the variables included without issue. I've done all I can to make the form as technically right as I can. I'm out of ideas. Changing the submit button doesn't resolve the issue either.

```
<form name="forminput" id="forminput">
<label for="accountname">Account Name :</label>
<input type="text" id="accountname" name="accountname">
<br>
<label for="startpopupDatepicker">Start Date : </label>
<input type="text" id="startpopupDatepicker" name="startpopupDatepicker">
<label for="endpopupDatepicker">End Date : </label>
<input type="text" id="endpopupDatepicker" name="endpopupDatepicker">
<br>
Node : <select id="nodename" name="nodename">
    <option value="EU">EU</option>
    <option value="US">US</option>
    <option value="APAC">APAC</option> </select>
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="Submit" onclick="history.go()">
</form>

<script>
//Input Start

var account = document.getElementById("accountname").value;
var node = document.getElementById('nodename').value;
var calstartdate = document.getElementById('startpopupDatepicker').value;
var calenddate = document.getElementById('endpopupDatepicker').value;

//Input End
//Chart Beginning

var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#chart',
data: {
    x : 'date',
    url: 'sqlcallcounts2.php?account='+account+'&node='+node+'&startdate='+calstartdate+'&enddate='+calenddate,
},
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `history.go()`? Why does the `<form>` element have no `action` attribute if you are presumably using the submit button to submit the page to a PHP url?

Comment: It reloads the page so that the javascript variables in the form can be out into the URL and load the graphs from that URL. The PHP URL is in the javascript that builds the graph and needs the data from the form put into the variables. 
There's no action because the form doesn't actually have to do anything other than gather the form data. I have tried several actions, including loading a duplicate of the page, though and this doesn't fix the issue. The form data still isn't being picked up and passed into the variables for the javascript to put into the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by making the whole of the Javascript that's in the page a function. I then used the onClick of the Submit button to active the function. It now works perfectly.